# (MySQL) How do you get the no of unique values in a column from the resultant table of a Natural Join in a single query?

Tags: mysql, count, unique, distinct, natural-join

I have two Tables:

Employee

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept, emp_sal

1         A           A         1

2         B           B         2

3         C           C         3

4         D           D         4
```

Trial

```
emp_id, random

1          X

1          Y

2          Z

3          A

4          B
```

If I were to perform a Natural join of Employee and Trial,

I would get the result:

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept, emp_sal random

1         A           A         1      X

1         A           A         1      Y

2         B           B         2      Z

3         C           C         3      A

4         D           D         4      B
```

If I wanted to perform the aforementioned Natural Join and count the no of depts in the organization in a single query, how would I go about doing that?

```
select count(emp_dept) from (select distinct(emp_dept) from employee natural join trial) as T2;
```

works, but I am wondering if there's another way to do the above?

Note:

Natural join is mandatory!

I tried both the following codes and failed miserably. :P

1. `select count(emp_dept) from (select (emp_dept) from employee natural join trial) as T2;`
   gave me 5, when the actual answer is 4.
2. `select count(select distinct(emp_dept) as emp_date from (select * from employee natural join trial) as T2) from T2;`
3. `select count(select distinct(emp_dept) as emp_date from (select * from employee natural join trial) as T2) from (select * from employee natural join trial) as T3);`

^ What did I do wrong in the 3 lines of code above?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just do a COUNT(DISTINCT .... )? Like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emp_dept) 
FROM employee 
NATURAL JOIN trial
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a ton, Kickstart!
(I would have voted up, had it not been for my amateur rep. :| )

Comment: ...and thank you, Ankur, for the edit. Still getting a hang of this wonderful website! xD